# Dependency Injection for Procedural Programming

Tags: dependency-injection, procedural-programming

Suppose I've decided to write a large application in C, or any other procedural programming language.  It has functions with call-dependencies that look like this:

```
A
|
+-------------+
|             |
B1            B2
|             |
+------+      +------+
|      |      |      |
C11    C12    C21    C22
```

Obviously, unit-testing the leaves functions, C11, C12, C21, and C22 is very easy: Setup the inputs, invoke the functions, assert the outputs.

But what is the proper strategy to enable good unit-testing for B1, B2 and A?

Would [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) suggest that `B1` (and `B2` also) be declared as followed?

```
// Declare B1 with dependency injection for invoking C11 and C12.
int B1(int input, int (*c11)(int), int(*c12)(int));
```

But that strategy does not seem scalable if I have many layers of calls.  Just imagine what the declaration for `A` would look like:

```
int A(int input, int (*b1)(int, int (*)(int), int(*)(int)), 
                 int(*b2)(int, int (*)(int), int(*)(int)),
                 int (*c11)(int),
                 int (*c12)(int),
                 int (*c21)(int),
                 int (*c22)(int));
```

Yuck!  There has to be a better way.

Sometimes, I feel that DI and other similar patterns that purport to promote modularity and ease of maintenance actually hampers code clarity and complicates what should be straightforward coding into nonsense abstractions and convoluted indirections.

How do large software projects in C, like Perl and Ruby, deals with unit-testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only require the DI for unit testing you may use the linker to do it.

What I mean is that the functions B1 & B2 are declared in a header and used by function A, so the implementation of the B functions is provided by the linker. You just need to provide a different C-File for unit tests. This should not be a big problem, as you probably have your own makefile for the unit test anyhow.

If you require dynamic dependency resolution at runtime you should use a factory pattern (a function returning the function-pointer) for function pointers and pull them from the factory when required. The factory may decide depending on global context what function to return.

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I will have to try it.

Comment: You may also program OO in C, not just procedural. Just declare a struct with data members and functions taking the struct as first argument (pseudo this pointer). Implementation in c file and you have created yourself a pseudo class. Polymorphism and things like that are possible, just complicated ;)

Answer (score 3):

`A` only needs to call `B1` and `B2`.  It does not need to know about anything at the C level.

You could inject a different dummy versions of functions `B1` and `B2` into `A` for the purpose of testing `A`.

This isolates `A` from needing the whole structure and means you can test each function in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

you can put the dependencies to a c-struct that will become one parameter for the function call. in c this would be similar to the file api where the first parameter is always the file-handle

Comment: We do a similar thing in other languages, have a service provider that has implementations of all kinds of dependencies in it. It has the added bonus of causing fewer changes to function signatures and making refactorings easier.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question.  It gets a bit tricky in procedural languages.... but I think you can borrow an idea from the OO world where folks often use constructor overloading to handle some of the DI work.  So for example you would use the default constructor that sets up all the dependencies as usual... but then also have another constructor that allows the dependencies to be injected.

Since you are procedural... I think you could  use function overloading to handle this for you.   Also when you are testing you only would need to mock out B1 & B2 when calling A... so you could simplify your DI for that purpose.  In other words if you really only using DI for unit testing then you don't have to inject the whole tree of dependcies only the first level dependecies...

So from A you might have...

```
int A(int input){
// create function point to b1 & b2 and call "return A(input, {pointer to b1},{pointer to b2})"
}
```

forgive my psuedo code it has been a long time since I did C.

Answer (score 0):

You can do proper unit testing of B1, B2 and A without DI. Just like the leaf functions, B1 and B2 has valid inputs and outputs, and you test those, same with A. That B1 can use C11 and C12 internally to help you fulfill its unit tests doesn't mean they have to be injected in cases where you don't need that flexibility.

Comment: But how does it scale?  On the specification, `A` will cover the functionalities of `B1` and `B2`, both of which also cover the functionalities of `C11`, `C12`, `C21`, and `C22`.

So, all the tests for the leaf functions `C11`, etc, would have to be repeated for all the node functions above them.  Now, imagine a deeply-layered set of codes.  You might find writing tests pretty laborious.

Comment: @Kirakun In practical cases A isn't doing the same as B1 and B2, it's adding some sort of extra functionality. If you have tests for B1 and B2 you can be confident in that part of the code. For A you then only test what you need to be confident about how it ties B1 and B2 together.

Comment: @tddtrying IMHO *unit* testing (in the scenario above) means testing `A` *without* testing (i.e. calling) functions in the B-level, not to mention C-level. B-level might be debatable but imagine that `C11` connects to a database. You don't want a unit test for `A` (or `B1`) to call the actual `C11` then. Instead some kind of mock-`C11` should be called.