# Unit-testing in Procedural or Functional Programming Languages

Tags: unit-testing, functional-programming, procedural-programming

I have asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527785/dependency-injection-for-procedural-programming), but I did not get a satisfactory answer.  So, perhaps I should ask it a different way.

How do large-scale C projects, like Perl or Ruby or even the Linux kernel, handle unit-testings?  Or even in any functional language?

I am familiar with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for testings in OOP, but I don't see a scalable and manageable equivalence in non OOP.  In C or Haskell, for example, there would be layers over layers of functions, higher ones implicitly calling the lower ones.  How do I find seams to test just an unit of code instead of all its dependencies?

One way to avoid the need for seams all together is to keep the depths of call-dependency graph very low.  Code horizontally rather than vertically, so to speak.  Keep as much of the application logic as possible in the "leaf" functions; and make sure the "node" functions do no work other than plumbing the data to other node/leaf functions.  Then, test only the "leaf" functions; leave the "node" functions out to integration tests.  Is that approach effective?

The largest software today are still written in procedural languages.  There must be some methodologies being employed that work.  Could someone with experience with large-scale software in procedural languages with good unit-testings comment?

Comment: I guess there must be something about this in "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers, a wonderful book btw.

Comment: Not just legacy code if you are referring to procedural languages.  But what about functional ones like Haskell, Lisp, Scheme, F#, etc.

Comment: You know of QuickCheck? This is a tool that can test "laws" (specificaions) of functions. It originates in the Haskell community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functional languages have other constructs (than objects) for modularity, such as ML functors. "Dependency injection" is basically a glorified name for "abstracting over things" and has been used for ages in functional languages.

Testing, in all paradigms, should follow the specification boundaries. If you have an idea what a given piece of code (function, method, object...) is supposed to do, you should test against this specification. For leaf functions, this will be unit testing, for "node" function this can be considered "integration testing" if you like, but it's really the same activity.

I think you will find that the same methodologies essentially applies to functional programming, with essentially the same results; in particular, (re)designing code to be easy to test also improves its modularity and maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

*designing code to be easy to test also improves its modularity and maintainability.*

Not true. Designing code to be easy to test improves the ease of writing test code.

Natural divisions of functional modules usually aren't the most convenient for unit testing. That's why so much Java code these days is broken into tiny, scattered pieces, with each piece mostly not useful by itself.